# Android ListView does not show line spacing

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set the line spacing color using the following code, but no lines are displayed. 
I am actually using the SwipeListView, but I do not think it matters

```
mylistview.setDividerHeight(1);
mylistviewsetBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your listview xml file

Answer (score 0):

found it...
not sure  why, but the order of calls are important...

```
mylistview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
mylistview.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you can use just a color. A drawable will definitely work.

drawable/divider_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="1dip" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

In your layout use

```
android:divider="@drawable/divider_white"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `xml` adding these attributes in `ListView`

```
android:divider="@android:color/white"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
```

Instead of color you can use any `drawable`